# Why is an accepted answer not counted in the Score of a Next tag badge?

Tags: discussion, support, badges

Why is the score of a tag not **counted** after you get an **accepted answer**?

If I answer a question with a **support tag**, why does this not count in the Next tag badge?

[image: Next tag badge]

Comment: An accept contributes to reputation of the OP but it doesn't change the score of an post. And that is what is needed for the tag badges. An accept also doesn't change the score of a post so it all seems logical.

Comment: mmm, ok @rene, maybe others can have another information, thank you any way.

Comment: @Braiam not sure, it's not trivial that acceptance is not related to score and it's not mentioned in that faq.

Comment: @rene why not post this as answer?

Comment: @ShadowWizard "What is this tag score you speak of? A tag score is basically the combined total of all the upvotes (+1) and downvotes (-1) you've accumulated on answers under that specific tag"

Comment: On another note as you removed you MSO post: maybe this query is what you were looking for http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/618616

Comment: @Braiam hmm... still, one might think that having an answer accepted also counts, OP here is pretty active user on SO, not some clueless newbie. So I think we better either edit the faq to make it clear acceptance doesn't count, or post answer here to clarify it. (as rene did in the comment)

Comment: well, I was on my way but @Patrick beat me to it ...

Comment: @rene sorry... :)

Comment: I'm never going to get that gold discussion badge @PatrickHofman I have to assume this is all part of your master plan ...

Comment: No. Than I would have quickly posted an answer. @rene

Comment: @rene discussion gold badge? That's easy. Get the bug gold badge...